# Intersection on values of table (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in the following manner:

---

```
Class | Dept | programs |        
.........................        
1     | 1    |2001      |     
.........................   
1     | 1    |2002      |     
.........................   
2     | 1    |2001      |     
.........................   
2     | 1    |2003      |     
.........................  
3     | 1    |2003      |     
.........................  
3     | 1    |2004      |     
.........................
```

The question I have is, when I select `select distinct programs where class in (1,2)` the query will return 2001, 2002, 2003. I want to select only those programs which are common for both 1 and 2 i.e. 2001. similarly when i search for class in (2,3) it should only return 2003.

Is this possible?

Comment: `it should only return 2002` ... this does not make sense based on your sample data.

Comment: For the class(2,3) there isnt anything in common to both 2 and 3.? How did you arrive at the return result of 2002

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the question. common between 2 and 3 is now 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3dec7232e5e25f15bf9144d662a7cf0a)**

```
select programs
from tablename t1
where class in (1,2)
group by programs
having count(distinct class) =2
```

Comment: That works like a charm. Could you elaborate on the `having count(distinct class) =2`. I would have to automate this, 2 resembles the number of classes i am searching for ?

Comment: You would know the number of elements you are binding in the "in" clause in this case it would be 2 for the elements 1 and 2. if you are binding 3 elements use the value of count(distinct class)=3